# Mixin SynchronizedSet with SortedSet having implicit Ordering object

Tags: scala, collections, implicit

I can't seem to create a SortedSet that also mixes in SynchronizedSet.  The crux of the problem is SortedSet requires an implicit Ordering object.

```
val orderByIdThenName = Ordering[(Int, String)].on[Foo](foo => foo.id -> foo.name)
new mutable.TreeSet[Foo]()(orderByIdThenName) // <- Works fine and is Ordered
new mutable.HashSet[Foo] with mutable.SynchronizedSet[Foo] // <- Mixin works
new mutable.TreeSet[Foo]()(orderByCount) with mutable.SynchronizedSet[Foo] // Fail!
```

The last line gives an error "Object creation impossible, since member Ordering[A] in scala.collection.SortedSetLike is undefined.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug in IntelliJ. I was able to reproduce the issue and see the error in the editor, but there are no errors or warnings on compiling.

Because there's no definition of orderByCount given, I'm assuming it's something like:

```
val orderByCount = Ordering[Int].on[Foo](_.count)
new mutable.TreeSet[Foo]()(orderByCount) with mutable.SynchronizedSet[Foo]
```

**UPDATE**:
Came up with a way to eliminate the error in IntelliJ by overriding `ordering`:

```
new mutable.TreeSet[Foo]()(orderByCount) with mutable.SynchronizedSet[Foo] {
    implicit override val ordering: Ordering[Foo] = orderByCount
}
```

Comment: That works well, thanks.  And yes, it looks like an IntelliJ bug.